# T-SQL Multiple Join on 1 Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm currently working on a complex T-SQL query in MS SQL Server 2012. I basically retrieve a basic list of projects, holding the ProjectId as well as the StaffVersionId (it is possible that the Staff changes throughout the project, although I hope it won't be the case :P ).

```
CREATE TABLE #BasicProjects
    (
        ProjectId INT
        , StaffVersionId INT
    )
```

Next I need to join on the ProjectData Table to get the Title of the project as well as join on the Employee Table to get the FullName of the Employee.

```
SELECT [P].ProjectId
    , [PD].Label AS Title
    , [E].Lastname + '' '' + Firstname AS Manager
    , [E].Lastname + '' '' + Firstname AS Contact
    FROM #BasicProjects [P]
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[ProjectData] [PD] ON [PD].ProjectDataId = [P].ProjectDataId 
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[Staff] [Y] ON [Y].StaffVersionId = [P].StaffVersionId AND [Y].StaffTypeId = 3 // Manager
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[Staff] [X] ON [X].StaffVersionId = [P].StaffVersionId AND [X].StaffTypeId = 2 // Contact
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] [E] ON [E].EmployeeId = [Y].EmployeeId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] [E] ON [E].EmployeeId = [X].EmployeeId
```

The query is kind of hard, because I have 2 kinds of staff employees 3 = Manager, 2 = Contact.

When I run my query I'm getting this error:

**The correlation name 'E' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.**

Do you know how to solve this error? Or perhaps some advises on how to improve this query?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need different aliases for each join (just like you did for `Staff`)

```
SELECT [P].ProjectId
    , [PD].Label AS Title
    , [YE].Lastname + ' ' + YE.Firstname AS Manager
    , [XE].Lastname + ' ' + XE.Firstname AS Contact
    FROM #BasicProjects [P]
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[ProjectData] [PD] ON [PD].ProjectDataId = [P].ProjectDataId 
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[Staff] [Y] ON [Y].StaffVersionId = [P].StaffVersionId AND [Y].StaffTypeId = 3 // Manager
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[Staff] [X] ON [X].StaffVersionId = [P].StaffVersionId AND [X].StaffTypeId = 2 // Contact
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] [YE] ON [YE].EmployeeId = [Y].EmployeeId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] [XE] ON [XE].EmployeeId = [X].EmployeeId
```

Comment: Ha, nice! That's it indeed! Thank you very much and have a great weekend!